# How to expand table so that each row is between two times?

Tags: mysql, sql

Apologies for the poorly worded question, hopefully I can explain it better here.

I have a "jobs" table with start and end times. I'm trying to explode the table so that each row corresponds to a 30 min time period that falls in between the start and end time.

For example, if a job starts at 10:45 and ends at 13:10, my first table would like like this:

| jobnumber | starthr | startmin | endhr | endmin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 10 | 45 | 13 | 10 |

I'd like to expand this single row to look something like this:

| jobnumber | time |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 10:30 |
| 12345 | 11:00 |
| 12345 | 11:30 |
| 12345 | 12:00 |
| 12345 | 12:30 |
| 12345 | 13:00 |

I've accomplished this by `CROSS JOIN`-ing a table with the different time segments, followed by a `CASE` to filter on the correct matches, but I'm curious to see if there is a better approach.

I'm using MySQL 5.6.

I've attached the basic schema below for convenience.

```sql
CREATE TABLE jobs (
    jobnumber INTEGER,
    starthr INTEGER,
    startmin INTEGER,
    endhr INTEGER,
    endmin INTEGER
);

-- job #12345 starts at 10:45 and ends 13:10
INSERT INTO jobs VALUES (12345, 10, 45, 13, 10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another way is to use `recursive cte`:

```
with recursive cte as(
select jobnumber
   , cast(concat(starthr,':',case when startmin < 30 then 0 else 30 end) as time) starttime
   , cast(concat(endhr,':',case when endmin < 30 then 0 else 30 end) as time) endtime
from jobs
union all 
select jobnumber,  starttime + interval 30 minute , endtime
from cte 
where starttime + interval 30 minute <= endtime
)

select jobnumber,starttime from cte
order by jobnumber,starttime;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6a0b056ebbcdb3d73dd79f9131cf98df)*

Comment: that worked, thanks! I was originally using v5.6, which didn't support the recursive CTE, so I had to update to the latest version to get things working.

Comment: oh 5.6 was not supported anyways , so that was as a wise decision to upgrade